# How to implement intelxdk using JavaScript in HTML?

Tags: intel-xdk

How & where should I implement this JavaScript method below in my index.html file?

I am using this code to access the native code of android in intelxdk

`smsplugin.startReception(successCallback(result),failureCallback(error));`

Answer (score 0):

You should implement your code in your .js file:

```
document.addListener('intel.xdk.device.ready', onXdkReady, false);

function onXdkReady() {
  if (smsplugin) {
    smsplugin.startReception(successCallback(result),failureCallback(error));
  }
}
```

See [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/493117) for more info.